# Unable to access existing fields in JSON object, keep getting undefined

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, lambda

I have a function in AWS Lambda in which I retrieve an unparsed JSON object, I parse it, and then access its values.

```
if(data.Payload){

            var parsedData = JSON.parse(data.Payload)
            console.log("PAYLOAD  --> " + parsedData);
            console.log("GROUPNAME --> " + parseData.groupName);
...
```

When I log to the console the parsedData variable, it seems like the parsing was successful:

```
PAYLOAD  --> {"groupName":"Hello!","membersCount":1,"searchField":"hello!"}
```

The issue arises when I try to access the fields in the JSON as I keep getting undefined:

```
GROUPNAME --> undefined
```

---

NOTE:

If I copy and paste the JSON object

```
{"groupName":"Hello!","membersCount":1,"searchField":"hello!"}
```

into a variable on the Chrome debugging console

```
var parsedData = {"groupName":"Hello!","membersCount":1,"searchField":"hello!"}
```

I am able to access the properties of the object as I am trying to do in the AWS Lambda function.

parsedData.groupName prints "Hello!"

---

**Edit - temporary solution**

The parsedData variable contains a String with a JSON, so the JSON object inside the "" I am not quite sure why. The temporary fix was to double parse the variable but that just seems wrong.

```
if(data.Payload){
            var parsedData = JSON.parse(data.Payload);
            var doubleParsed = JSON.parse(parsedData);
            if(doubleParsed.groupName !== undefined) {
                console.log(doubleParsed.groupName);
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

If that is a copy paste of your code, in your 2nd console.log you are using `parseData` NOT `parsedData` missing a D.

**EDIT** Just adding as answer what I wrote in comments.

It seems `parsedData` was not being parsed correctly, for some reason `JSON.parse` is not working, I think some information about `data.Payload` is needed to know what it exactly returns.

Yet the next code seems to solve it, but I would honestly need further explanation as why it needs to be done twice:

```
var parsedData = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data.Payload));
```

Comment: Thank you! just edited the question to fix that. It was not copy paste, I just made a mistake typing, the problem still stands :/

Comment: I just noticed, your first `console.log()` should have a different output if your are logging a Json object, the output should be `[Object object]` if parsed correctly, which makes me think the JSON object is not being parsed, it may be wrong somewhere. If parsed correctly you should probably be using `console.log(JSON.stringify(parsedData))` 
This makes me think `data.Payload` is not an actual JSON or has a mistake in it.

Comment: @alan you should try making a `console.log(data.Payload)` or `console.log(JSON.stringify(data.Payload))` to see what it contains.

Comment: Thank you Alan, what you are saying is right, parsedData seems to be a string. If I parse the object again it becomes an actual JSON object and I am able to access its fields. I am not sure why it does not get parsed correctly and I doubt that the solution is to parse it twice.

(I'll copy my code in the question as an edit)

Comment: I'm confused on why it doesn't works the first time, I'm reading through some questions that may be related. If I find why it has to be done twice, I'll come back and post the reason.